# In Uplink, do CPU upgrades transfer to new gateways?

Tags: uplink

If I buy the best CPU at the start of the game, and then upgrade my gateway, will the new gateway have my CPU installed in it or will I lose it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your hardware will be transferred into the new gateway, assuming the gateway supports it. If your new gateway does not support a particular piece of hardware (e.g. your current modem is 10GQps, new gateway only supports up to 8GQps modems), it will be lost. If your new gateway doesn't have enough slots to fit all the components of a particular type, the extra components will be lost too.

Comment: thanks. so if I buy the CPU, and then upgrade to another gateway (but one which only supports 1xCPU), will it replace the default CPU with mine, or will it only use my CPU if the new gateway supports 2 or more CPUs?

Comment: @cantsay gateways (apart from your starting one) don't have default components, so all of your components will be migrated if the new gateway has at least as many slots of a particular type as your old gateway had components. The only case where you would get a "stock" component is if the new gateway doesn't support your old component because it's too high-grade.